# Create nested file nodes Gatsby 4

Tags: gatsby

Since Gatsby 4 doesn't accept remoteFileNodes to be created within the `createResolvers` API inside `gatsby-node.js`, i'm looking for another solution to create File's from our remote (graphql) source.

Creating files on the upper level of an object works just fine, however i can't find a way to create these files inside nested objects in my schema.

Although there is a `File` object created with the provided name inside Sections, all the data inside of it results in null. The given URL is checked and is valid.

The following code is inside my `gatsby-node.js` file:

**sourceNodes**

```
exports.sourceNodes = async ({ actions, createContentDigest, createNodeId }) => {
  const { createNode } = actions;

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query {
        
        PageContent {
          id
          main_image_url
          blocks {
            title
            sections {
              title
              nested_image_url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  });

  data.PageContent.forEach((pageContent) => {
    createNode({
      ...pageContent,
      id: createNodeId(`${PAGE_CONTENT}-${pageContent.id}`),
      parent: null,
      children: [],
      internal: {
        type: PAGE_CONTENT,
        content: JSON.stringify(pageContent),
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(pageContent),
      }
    })
  });

  return;
};
```

**onCreateNode**

```
exports.onCreateNode = async ({
  node,
  actions: { createNode, createNodeField },
  createNodeId,
  getCache,
}) => {

  if (node.internal.type === PAGE_CONTENT) {
```

> This works just fine

```
    if (node.main_image_url) {
      const fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
        url: node.main_image_url,
        parentNodeId: node.id,
        createNode,
        createNodeId,
        getCache,
      });
  
      if (fileNode) {
        createNodeField({ node, name: "main_image", value: fileNode.id });
      }
    }
```

> But this won't

```
    if (node.blocks && node.blocks.length > 0) {
      node.blocks.map(async({ sections }) => {

        if (sections.length > 0) {

          sections.map(async(section) => {

            if (section.nested_image_url) {

              const fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
                url: section.nested_image_url,
                parentNodeId: node.id,
                createNode,
                createNodeId,
                getCache,
              });
  
              if (fileNode) {
                createNodeField({ node, name: "nested_image", value: fileNode.id });
              }
            }
          })
        }
      })
    }
  }
};
```

**createSchema**

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;

  createTypes(`
    type PageContent implements Node {
      main_image: File @link(from: "fields.main_image")
      blocks: [Block]
    }

    type Block {
      sections: [Section]
    }

    type Section {
      nested_image: File @link(from: "fields.nested_image")
    }
  `);
};
```

Would be really grateful if someone has a clue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I've come to a solution, which includes the use of the `onCreateNode` and `createSchemaCustomization` API's

#### onCreateNode

```
  // Single Node

  const fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
     url: node.image,
     parentNodeId: node.id,
     createNode,
     createNodeId: (id) => `${node.unique_identifier_prop}-image`,
     getCache,
   });

    // Array

    await Promise.all(
      node.images.map((url, index) => (
        createRemoteFileNode({
          url: url,
          parentNodeId: node.id,
          createNode,
          createNodeId: id => `${node.unique_identifier_prop}-images-${index}`,
          getCache,
        })
      ))
    )
```

First you can create a FileNode to your own liking, and instead of the API's createNodeId function. We replace it by a unique and retrievable identifier, so we can locate the File Node in our Schema.

#### createSchemaCustomization

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = async({ actions, schema }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;

  const typeDefs = [
    schema.buildObjectType({
      name: `**target_typename**`,
      fields: {
        // Single Node
        imageFile: {
          type: 'File',
          resolve: (source, args, context, info) => {
            return context.nodeModel.getNodeById({
              id: `${source.unique_identifier_prop}-image`,
              type: 'File',
            })
          }
        },
        // Array
        imageFiles: {
          type: '[File]',
          resolve: (source, args, context, info) => {
            const images = source.images.map((img, index) => (
              context.nodeModel.getNodeById({
                id: `${source.unique_identifier_prop}-images-${index}`,
                type: 'File',
              })
            ))
            return images
          }
        },
      }
    })
  ];

  createTypes(typeDefs)
};
```

In the `createSchemaCustomization` we now can define our custom type with the `buildObjectType` function provided by schema, which is available in this API.

In the resolver, we can retrieve the node's values with the `source` parameter, which holds our `unique_identifier_prop`. Now, with the `context` parameter, we can use the `getNodeById` function to retrieve the File Node that is bound to our provided ID. Finally, we can return the found File Node and attach it to our Node.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the solution I found was to use `createResolvers`.

```
    exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }) => {
    const resolvers = {
        HomePageValuesBannerImage: {
            bannerImageFile: {
                type: "File",
                resolve: async (source, args, context, info) => {
                    const homePage = await context.nodeModel.findRootNodeAncestor(source)
                    const imageId = homePage.fields.bannerImage
                    const imageNode = await context.nodeModel.getNodeById({
                        id: imageId,
                    })

                    return imageNode
                },
            },
        },
    }
    createResolvers(resolvers)
}
```

So the first thing I needed was to access the `fields` field on my parent object, because whenever you use `createNodeField` it creates a field with the name you provide inside the node on `fields`.

To access the node file id that is stored on `fields`, in my case is called `bannerImage` on your example `nested_image`, you first need a reference of the parent node so in order to do that I use `context.nodeModel.findRootNodeAncestor(source)` source is just a reference of the nested property. In my case is `HomePageValuesBannerImage` because my data looks like this:

```
HomePage {
 Values {
  banner {
   image
  }
 }
}
```

and in my schema the banner property's type is HomePageValuesBannerImage.

Then you need to create a new field, on the documentation says that [is better to create a new field than updating one.](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization/#createresolvers-api)

The field I created is called `bannerImageFile` and inside that field is going to be the File Node.

After making the query for the parent of my nested node I just extract the file id that is stored inside `fields` in my custom field called `bannerImage`.

And finally I made a query to find a node by its ID and return it.

```
const imageNode = await context.nodeModel.getNodeById({
                        id: imageId,
                    })
```

Im still looking for a different approach to this problem, but this is the best solutions I could find.

Comment: Thanks José! I've come to a similar solution, but in the createSchemaCustomization API. I would be happy to share if you like, since i think thats a more proper location for editing Schema's.

Comment: It would be really nice if you share your solution :)

Comment: I’ve posted my solution above, and marked it as answer! Hopefully it can be of use for you ^^