# How to create Gatsby Image data for nested nodes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to use [createRemoteFileNode](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/) to create optimised images for an array of nodes that exist on a `Product`.

I have a `Product` that has `items` and on each item, it has a `featuredImg`. I can create a featuredImg for a `Product` but as soon as I try to create it for the child nodes (items) then it is not queryable.

I am creating my nodes as such:

```js
const products = [
  {
    id: "product_1",
    imageUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1665081661649-8656335a6cbb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1738&q=80",
    items: [
      {
        id: 'item_1',
        imageUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1666120565124-7e763880444a?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1770&q=80"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const sourceNodes = async ({ actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest }, options) => {
  
  products.forEach((testNode) => {
    const node = {
      ...testNode,
      id: createNodeId(`Product-${testNode.id}`),
    }

    actions.createNode({
      ...node,
      internal: {
        type: 'Product',
        contentDigest: createContentDigest(node),
      },
    });

    testNode.items.forEach(item => {

      const itemNode = {
        ...item,
        id: createNodeId(`Item-${item.id}`),
      }
  
      actions.createNode({
        ...itemNode,
        parent: node.id,
        internal: {
          type: 'Item',
          contentDigest: createContentDigest(itemNode),
        },
      });

    })
  })
};

module.exports = sourceNodes;
```

Then on the node creation, I am running the `onCreateNode` function which should create the remote file node for each item featuredImg.

```js
const { createRemoteFileNode } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`);

const onCreateNode = async ({ node, cache, store, getCache, actions: { createNode, createNodeField }, createNodeId }) => {  
  
  if( node.internal.type === 'Item') {
    
    const fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
      url: node.imageUrl,
      parentNodeId: node.parent,
      createNode,
      createNodeId,
      getCache,
    })

    if (fileNode) {
      createNodeField({ node, name: "localFile", value: fileNode.id })
    }
  }
  
  if( node.internal.type === 'Product') {
    
    const fileNode = await createRemoteFileNode({
      url: node.imageUrl,
      parentNodeId: node.id,
      createNode,
      createNodeId,
      getCache,
    })

    if (fileNode) {
      createNodeField({ node, name: "localFile", value: fileNode.id })
    }
  }
};

module.exports = onCreateNode
```

I have defined my types here:

```
module.exports = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;
  const typeDefs = `
    type Product implements Node {
      id: String!
      imageUrl: String!
      featuredImg: File @link(from: "fields.localFile")
      items: [Item]
    }

    type Item implements Node {
      id: String!
      imageUrl: String!
      featuredImg: File @link(from: "fields.localFile")
    }
  `;
  createTypes(typeDefs);
};
```

For some reason, when I query `Products.items[i].featuredImg` it always returns null. However, I can see the node is generated because I can query `item.featuredImg` and it returns the `gatsbyImageData`.

I have created a simple example here and included a read me on how to replicate it: https://github.com/stretch0/gatsby-sandbox

I have also noticed that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71207509/create-nested-file-nodes-gatsby-4) is a similar issue of not being able to create remote file nodes within a loop but because they have a different file structure, I can't figure out how their solution to use `createSchemaCustomization` or `createResolvers` would apply to my setup.